# PDF file name issue in apex Send Mail method

Tags: apex, pdf, apex-email-service

I want to add date to a PDF file name.

I am sending an email from apex and attaching one PDF file with it.

Now I want to set string with dynamic date with it.

E.g....

```
date fromdate = date.newinstance((i.startdate__c.day(),i.startdate__c.month(),i.startdate__c.year());
date todate = date.newinstance((i.startdate__c.day(),i.startdate__c.month(),i.startdate__c.year()+1);

string formateddate1 = fromdate.format(MM d, yyyy);
string formateddate2 = todate.format(MM d, yyyy);

att.setfilename('my file' +formateddate1 'to' +formateddate2);
```

It's showing PDF name like -    **my file  0000-11-06-08 00 00 to 0000-12-06-08 00 00**

it's showing time also and wrong date. How do i correct it? I want only date without time

Answer (score 4):

The `Date` class does not have a `format` method that takes a formatting string but the `Datetime` class does. You can create `Datetime` without having to set time parts and then format it:

```
Datetime dtFrom = Datetime.newInstance(
        i.startdate__c.year(),
        i.startdate__c.month(),
        i.startdate__c.day()
        );
String formattedFrom = dtFrom.format('MM d, yyyy');
```

Note the ordering of the year/month/day arguments too. Also see [format options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).